# Magento 2 Custom option value filed

Tags: magento2, custom-options, custom-field

> I would like to add value field. Find the below screenshot for custom
>   options in magento2

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code.

```
$productFactory = $this->_objectManager->get("\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory");
$product = $productFactory->create()->load(1);
$options = $product->getOptions();
// \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface
$productOptionValue = $this->_objectManager->create("\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value");

$newValue = array(
        "sku" => "xxl", 
        "title" => "XXL",  
        "price" => 10,
        "price_type" => "percent"
    );
$productOptionValue->addValue($newValue);


if(count($options) > 0) {
    foreach($options as $key=>$option){ 
        if($option->getTitle() == "Size"){      
            try {
                $productOptionValue->setOption($option)->saveValues();   
                echo "value added";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
               echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Instead of Using _objectManager define class in to __construct method